# Having new issue on 2nd go-through with Unity Tutorial

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

this script is supposed to be spawning an object every 2 seconds or so, but, it seems to be insta-spawning a million endlessly instead. I'll be fixing them further in making them get destroyed once off-screen so that's not an issue. But what I do need to do is have it properly delay executing

```
InvokeRepeating()
```

Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject obstaclePrefab;
    private Vector3 spawnPOS = new Vector3(25, 0, 0);
    private float startDelay = 2;
    private float repeatRate = 2;
    

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
        {
            InvokeRepeating("SpawnObstacle", startDelay, repeatRate);
        }

    }

    void SpawnObstacle()
    {
        Instantiate(obstaclePrefab, spawnPOS, obstaclePrefab.transform.rotation);
    }
}
```

Doesn't seem to matter what I put in as `repeatRate`, 2 and 20 seem similar. Although just 2 should be fine... it was a few days ago the first time I put this together.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: Side Note: The only difference between this time and the first time is this time I loaded as 3D URP instead of just 3D & Unity Editor Version 2021.3.14f1 instead of 2021.3.13f1

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `InvokeRepeating` from `Update`.  That will start a new timer every frame.  You even have a comment in there that says:

> ```
> // Update is called once per frame
> ```

It's true!

Presumably your updates are occurring 60-ish times per second.  So I would expect that **after the initial 2-second delay** that **120-ish objects** would be created.  Which is neither ***insta-spawning*** nor is it ***a "million"***.  (I'm a bit picky about reporting the details of things accurately.)  But the timers will remain active and continue to spawn new instances, and the total number *will* grow *quadratically* (the number of objects will be proportional to elapsed time squared) so I'm sure it *seems* like *a million*.

Likely you intended the `InvokeRepeating` call to be in your `Start` method, not the `Update` method.  That way you only start one repeating timer.

Comment: That was it, moving it to Start fixed my issue, thank you. For my own reference, is there a way to make Update time oriented instead of framerate oriented?

Comment: You have choices.  But easiest may be to check `Time.deltaTime` in the Update method to see how much time has elapsed against the "wall clock" and then _conditionally_ do something logical based on the elapsed time.

Comment: Thank you @Wyck. I never used my programming degree and recently quit everything to become an Indie Game Dev and this is like week 2 of going through tutorials. Thank you for everything.

Comment: @SimsStudiosLLC glad you got it going and congratulations on becoming an indie game dev.